# Path-Independence and the Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

My question concerns the path-independence integrals calculated using the residue theorem.

Consider the integral $$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\! \frac{1}{(z+i)(z+2i)(z+3i)}\ \mathrm{d}z. $$

It seems that by integrating over different contours, one could arrive at different values of $I$.  For example, if one chose a semi-circle in the upper half-plane as a contour, applying Cauchy's Residue Theorem would show $I=0$.  On the other hand if, if one chose a contour in the lower half-plane, one would arrive at $I=-2\pi i\sum_{j=1}^3\mathrm{Res}(f;z_j)$, where $z_j=-i,\ -2i, -3i$.  However, it seems like the value of $I$ should be unique and not depend upon the chosen contour.

Is this logic correct?  This question is driving me mad, and I would very much appreciate any help!!

Edit: Forgot a minus sign in application of Residue Theorem.

Comment: If you chose a semi circle in the upper half plane, since the singularities are not enclosed by the contour, integral is zero. However, if you are considering a semi circle in the lower half-plane, this will enclose the singularities at $-i$, $-2i$ and $-3i$ then residue theorem gives zero...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the second method (lower half-plane) you have
$$
I=-2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{(-i+2i)(-i+3i)}+\frac{1}{(-2i+i)(-2i+3i)}+\frac{1}{(-3i+i)(-3i+2i)}\right)=0
$$
so you have $0$ with both methods.
(I'm assuming the integral is over reals)

Comment: (+1) Clear and concise.  Just one point ... technically, $I=-2\pi i \sum_n \text{Res}(f, z=z_n)$ since the contour in the lower-half plane is traversed clockwise.  I've edited accordingly.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I was just thinking about that minus!

Comment: Yes, I should have had the minus sign in my question to begin with!  This makes complete sense, thanks so much for the answer! The Residue Theorem never ceases to amaze me...

Comment: Just added the minus sign to the question.

Comment: You're welcome!